# In which package of r is the function "envrmt"?

Tags: r, dataframe, environment, opencsv, tabulate

I wanted to use a csv-file as data.frame to work with.
I wrote:

```
df <- read.table(paste0(environment$path_data_csv,"C:/Users/Muench/edu/mpg-envinsys-plygrnd/Datenanalyse/mpg-data-analysis-2019-Muenchj4/hessen_holzeinschlag_1997-2014.csv"),
                 skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
```

The out put was:

> object 'envrmt' not found

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen that error, but I think you would remove at least one error from your code by changing your first argument.

This is already an absolute path:

```
"C:/Users/Muench/edu/mpg-envinsys-plygrnd/Datenanalyse/mpg-data-analysis-2019-Muenchj4/hessen_holzeinschlag_1997-2014.csv"
```

Therefore unless `environment$path_data_csv` is `NULL`, this will be an invalid file path:

```
paste0(environment$path_data_csv, "C:/Users/Muench/edu/mpg-envinsys-plygrnd/Datenanalyse/mpg-data-analysis-2019-Muenchj4/hessen_holzeinschlag_1997-2014.csv")
```

However, reading in the CSV using either one of the above file paths below may work:

```
df <- read.table("C:/Users/Muench/edu/mpg-envinsys-plygrnd/Datenanalyse/mpg-data-analysis-2019-Muenchj4/hessen_holzeinschlag_1997-2014.csv",
                 skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",") 
# OR
df <- read.table(environment$path_data_csv, 
                 skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
```